Issue with AWS Location Service HTTP POST Request in Flutter: ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error
I'm encountering a problem while trying to make an HTTP POST request to AWS Location Service from my Flutter app. I'm using an API key for authentication, and the request is intended to fetch address suggestions. However, I consistently receive a ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error without further details. Here’s a simplified version of my code:
final String baseUrl = 'https://geo.us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
final String apiKey = 'my_api_key_here';
final String path = '/places/v0/indexes/platgestao/search/suggestions';
final Uri uri = Uri.parse(baseUrl + path);

try {
  final response = await http.post(
    uri,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'x-api-key': apiKey,
    },
    body: json.encode({
      'Text': query,
      'MaxResults': 5,
    }),
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final data = json.decode(response.body);
    // Handle data here
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load suggestions');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print('Error fetching address suggestions: $e');
}

I've verified the correctness of the baseUrl, apiKey.
Could someone help me identify what might be causing this XMLHttpRequest error? Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

This is a CORS error as the AWS server is not including the relevant CORS headers. Note that you should not attempt to enable CORS headers on the server, even if there are settings (which I hope not) as you should never access an API that needs a key directly from the browser. (Your key will be easily stolen.) Instead add an API on the server from which you will host the application and call those (does not need CORS). Your API key will then be safely stored in your server, rather than being easily found in the browser.

Hi Richard! Thank you for your help!
I will host the application on AWS via Amplify gen2 (back and fron-end). What path do you judge more correct in this case? In my App I use the amplify auth solution with Cognito, but when I tried to use the current user credentials for this porpouse, found the same problem.
Amplify gen2 doesn't offer a pre built solution for integration, only via CDK, wich Location Service doesn't have a valid construct  on constructs.dev yet. Thanks!
